# Habilitar https en asterisk

Tags: https, asterisk

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es lo que tengo actualmente dentro al  mostrar el estado del servidor

Comment: Te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow, te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida ¡Y obtendrás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)! Si tienes dudas, puedes consular el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener más información acerca de un posible error en el inicio ejecutando el servicio de la siguiente manera:

```
asterisk -rvvvv
```

El error es relacionado con TLS porque puede que no se haya realizado bien alguno de los siguientes puntos:

1. Crea un certificado:

   `./ast_tls_cert -C pbx.example.com -O "My Super Company" -d /etc/asterisk/keys`

   Cambia `pbx.example.com` por la dirección de tu compañía o por la IP de tu máquina.
   Si no encuentras el script puedes descargarlo aquí [ast_tls_cert](https://github.com/asterisk/asterisk/blob/master/contrib/scripts/ast_tls_cert)
2. Modifica el fichero `/etc/asterisk/http.conf` y añade lo siguiente:

```
[general]
enabled=yes
bindaddr=0.0.0.0
bindport=8088
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089
tlscertfile=<your_cert_file>
```

Cambia `<your_cert_file>` por tu fichero `*.pem`. En el paso 1 se añaden en `/etc/asterisk/keys` y por defecto se nombra como `asterisk.pem`.

3. Da permisos de acceso a los certificados creados en el paso 1:

   `chmod 755 /etc/asterisk/keys`
4. Cambia el propietario de la carpeta de certificados al usuario `asterisk`:

   `chown -R asterisk /etc/asterisk/keys`
5. Añade los certificados creados a los objetos PJSIP en `/etc/asterisk/pjsip.conf`:

```
[webrtc_client]
type=endpoint
aors=webrtc_client
auth=webrtc_client
dtls_cert_file=<your_cert_file>
dtls_ca_file=<your_ca_cert_file>
webrtc=yes
; Setting webrtc=yes is a shortcut for setting the following options:
; use_avpf=yes
; media_encryption=dtls
; dtls_verify=fingerprint
; dtls_setup=actpass
; ice_support=yes
; media_use_received_transport=yes
; rtcp_mux=yes
context=default
disallow=all
allow=opus
allow=ulaw``
```

Cambia `<your_cert_file>` por tu fichero `*.pem`. En el paso 1 se añade en `/etc/asterisk/keys` y por defecto se nombra como `asterisk.pem`. Modifica, también, `<your_ca_cert_file>` por tu fichero `ca.crt`. En el paso 1 se añade en `/etc/asterisk/keys` y por defecto se nombra como `ca.crt`.

6. Añade los certificados creados a los objetos SIP en `/etc/asterisk/sip.conf`:

```
[webrtc_client]
host=dynamic
secret=199 ; This is a completely insecure password.  Do NOT expose this 
;             system to the Internet without utilizing a better password.
context=default
type=friend
encryption=yes
avpf=yes
force_avp=yes
icesupport=yes
directmedia=no
disallow=all
allow=opus
allow=ulaw
dtlsenable=yes
dtlsverify=fingerprint
dtlscertfile=<your_cert_file>
dtlscafile=<your_ca_cert_file>
dtlssetup=actpass
rtcp_mux=yes
```

Cambia `<your_cert_file>` por tu fichero `*.pem`. En el paso 1 se añade en `/etc/asterisk/keys` y por defecto se nombra como `asterisk.pem`. Modifica, también, `<your_ca_cert_file>` por tu fichero `ca.crt`. En el paso 1 se añade en `/etc/asterisk/keys` y por defecto se nombra como `ca.crt`.

7. Por último, reinicia el servicio para aplicar los cambios:

   `asterisk -rx "core restart when convenient"`

Comment: Si se va a utilizar varios endpoints (usuarios SIP) con esta configuracion, se recomienda crear una plantilla en SIP con los parametros del certificado, encryption, avpf, force_avp, icesupport, incluso los codecs, asi al crear nuevos dispositivos SIP, solo haces la referencia a la plantilla y se heredan. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Edita el fichero `/etc/asterisk/http.conf` (o el directorio especifico de tu SO). Que queden habilitados los siguientes campos, sin cambiar los ya existentes:

```
[general]
tlsenable=yes
tlsbindaddr=0.0.0.0:8089
tlscertfile=<your_cert_file>
tlsprivatekey=<your_key_file>
tlscafile=<your_ca_cert_file>
```

Substituye `<your_cert_file>`por tus certificados.

Acepta certificados auto signados, por supuesto.

Reinicia servicio y comprueba la salida de `http status`  desde la misma consola asterisk.

[Mas información a la documentación oficial](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40818091)